# The batch file to edit Host file is continuosly running without stopping

Tags: batch-file

```
@Echo off
:: Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
:: If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
Echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
Echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
Echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
Exit /B
:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( Del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
Pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

I am using the above batch file to edit host file. In windows 7, by default the UAC prompt is not coming. So i used this one.
However, when a user do not have admin rights to edit the host file, it is continuously running the if loop and to stop the process we need to log off or restart the system.

So can anyone please suggest any change in the batch file, so that it will just run once or twice and if not get the admin rights then just exit.

Thank you
Sibasundar

Answer (score 1):

Add a parameter to the script that lets it know if it was self invoked.  If the script was self invoked and does not have admin privs then exit.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

set "VBS=%Temp%\getadmin.vbs"

:: Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SystemRoot%\System32\cacls.exe" "%SystemRoot%\System32\config\system"
if "%ErrorLevel%"=="0" goto gotAdmin
if /i "%~1"=="Self" exit /b 1
goto UACPrompt


:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%VBS%"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "Self %*", "", "runas", 1 >> "%VBS%"
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
"%VBS%"
exit /b 1


:gotAdmin
shift
if exist "%VBS%" del "%VBS%"
pushd "%CD%"
cd /d "%~dp0"
"%SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.exe" "%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
popd
endlocal
```

### Update:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

set "ExitCode=0"
set "VBS=%Temp%\getadmin.vbs"

:: Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SystemRoot%\System32\cacls.exe" "%SystemRoot%\System32\config\system"
if "%ErrorLevel%"=="0" goto gotAdmin
if /i "%~1"=="Self" goto ElevateFail
goto UACPrompt


:ElevateFail
set "ExitCode=1"
echo Error: Administrator privileges are required.
pause>nul
goto End


:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%VBS%"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "Self %*", "", "runas", 1 >> "%VBS%"
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
"%VBS%"
goto End


:gotAdmin
shift
if exist "%VBS%" del "%VBS%"
pushd "%CD%"
cd /d "%~dp0"
"%SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.exe" "%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
popd


:End
endlocal & exit /b %ExitCode%
```

Comment: Thanks David. Its awesome. One more little help if you can provide. I just need to show a message if the user do not have admin rights..........

Comment: i am speechless. you just helped me a lot. Thank you sooooooooooooooooo much for your support. You are awesome.......

Comment: one more help needed. The batch file is working fine. However when i create a exe file using iexpress, the echo/message is not coming (i.e. the :ElevateFail part). It is simply exiting.

Comment: The `:ElevateFail` part should only display if the user says No to the UAC prompt or if the user fails to obtain administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:PAUSE` at the end of your code.

```
@Echo off
:: Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
:: If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
Echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
Echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
Echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
Exit /B
:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( Del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
Pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
:PAUSE
```